# Who founded Rome?

Tags: ancient-rome, classical-antiquity

According to [myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_of_Rome) ". . .

> the Trojan refugee Aeneas escape[d] to Italy and found[ed] the line of
> Romans through his son Iulus, the namesake of the Julio-Claudian
> dynasty."

*Aside: Livy (1797). The history of Rome. George Baker (trans.). Printed for A.Strahan

> The founding of Rome was known to be a myth and Romulus and Remus were
> founders of Rome and Romulus killed Remus to control Rome at the
> time.*

Is there a evidence to suggest that refugees from Troy founded Rome?

Comment: None whatsoever. There are some *legends* that *[the descendants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romulus_and_Remus)* of those refugees founded Rome, though.

Comment: There's some DNA evidence that suggests the Etruscans and other Latins _may_ have migrated to Italy from Asia Minor, which _may_ offer a (very broad) historical background to Rome's foundation myth. That said, it's still a myth, and that's very clearly pointed out in the Wikipedia article you linked. I'm not 100% sure what the question is here.

Comment: This is kind of a question easily answered by Wikipedia. Thanks for letting me know if I am allowed to edit the question or not. I was uncertain about that.

Comment: From the [site's help center](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/editing): "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you." You consistently resist people trying to improve your questions. Perhaps it's time to consider moving somewhere else for your history questions.

Answer (score 8):

Even the legends make no such statement. Aeneas and his followers travel to Latium, the area near the site of Rome and mix with the population.  Later, Romulus and Remus, of the line of the Kings of the Latin town of Alba Longa found Rome.  According to myth, the Kings of Alba Longa are linked to the Trojans.

Julius Caesar's family traced their heritage back to Aeneas himself, and was proud of that link to the God Venus.

Answer (score 6):

Herodotus and other ancient writers claimed the [Etruscans were immigrants](http://www.ancient-wisdom.co.uk/italyetruscans.htm) from Asia minor, possibly from the area of Lydia. It's sometimes asserted that they came west in search of metal: they were famous in antiquity for their metalworking skills and (the theory goes) they came from a much more technoiogically advanced area to exploit the resources of the area.

Given the undoubted intermingling of Etruscans and Romans in the early days of Rome, it's not hard to see how this could give rise to the legend of Trojan immigration to Latium.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etruscan_origins

Comment: Yes, but such a migration happened way before there was anything like Lydia and the Trojan war. While many mention this DNA study, they do not mention that time depth, which surpasses the events in the Iliad.